Manually trigger automated Software & Updates process
This is going to sound like a silly question but please bare with me.  I'm trying to figure a way, on an Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS system how to "Test" the automated Software Updater utility.  To be specific, it's possible for the user to schedule the frequency that updates are checked within the Software & Updates utility.  It looks like it's changing a value in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic.
All I really want to do, regardless of what the user has set, I'd like to manually trigger whatever "automagically" gets executed by this schedule on a system to validate that the automated built in updating process is working as expected.
To be clear, this isn't a "run sudo apt update/upgrade -y" issue.  This is more along the lines of when I update our onsite Ubuntu repository mirror, on a select number of systems I'd like to test the process that automatically checks for updates and notifies the user.
My sincere thanks for any help and/or guidance.

You may be looking for sudo unattended-upgrade. You may want to add the option --debug or the option --dry-run.
